# My collider is not following my humanoid animation: how to do ?

Tags: unity, collider

I've a "Zombie" charachter and the following hirearchy:

[image]

I put a Capsule collider on parent Zombie_01. 
When I kill the zombie, my "Zombie dead" animation is played, Zombie fall to ground, but the capsule collider stay standing.

So my question is: where I've to put capsule collider ? Or, what am i wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a rigid body with your image. If you won't have one then the collider can't react under physical condition changes.

Comment: I also have a rigidbody on parent object Zombie_01 ..

Comment: ok then it must be a non dynamic rigid-body !
Kinematic rigid bodies don't take effect of Physical collisions.